# Mostrar texto desde código HTML

Tags: java, html

Tengo una String de código HTML en Java, y querría mostrarla como texto normal en otra String, para mostrarla en un word o algo así.
 Ejemplo tengo esto:

```html
<ul>
  <li style="text-align: center;">Prueba contenido</li>
  <li style="text-align: center;">para pdf</li>
</ul>
```

Y querría verlo asi pero tabulado:

- Prueba contenido
- para pdf

¿Hay alguna manera?

Comment: A que te refieres con tabulado?

Comment: te refieresa  que el `·` esté en el centro junto al texto?

Comment: Me refiero a que este centrado, que no sabia mostrarlo con el editor de stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Lo hice un tanto rapido. Pero debes entender que el `<ul>` es quien contiene el `·`. Por tanto si modificamos es margen de este, posicionandolo a nuestro gusto, entonces tendremos nuestro `·` donde queremos que esté.

```html
<ul style="margin-left: 150px;">
  <li>Prueba contenido</li>
  <li>para pdf</li>
</ul>
```

Si te fijas bien en las imagenes, con la herramienta de desarrollador, puedes darte cuenta que este elemento pertenece a `<ul>` y no a `<li>`

**Focus a `<li>`**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Focus a `<ul>`**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que esto pueda serte de ayuda!

Comment: Creo que me explicado mal, lo que tengo es en java, una string, y querría tener una string de texto plano, sustituyendo los tags por lo que correspondan en texto